# Как перенаправить запрос к одному ip на другой?

Tags: python

С помощью модуля socket , я подключаюсь к одному ip. Передать я ему должен переменную data. Но у меня возник другой вопрос. Как можно отправить ему переменную data, но сделать так, чтобы эта data перенаправилась уже на другой ip. Слышал что это можно реализовать заголовками, но точно не знаю как. Можете ли вы написать простой пример этого?

Comment: у вас есть доступ к компам 2 и 3 ?

Comment: @Интик, мне необходимо подключиться через socket к прокси серверу, а далее послать на прокси что то так, чтобы прокси это перенаправил на ip сайтa. Грубо говоря, проксированный запрос. Но я не понимаю, как сделaть, чтобы с прокси перенаправилось на ip сайта